# How can I connect to a deployment server on a different network?

Tags: django, remote-access

I'm working through the Django book, and I set up everything I need to in order to use the development server. However, I'm running it on a server not on my network. I know you can view the development site while on the network, but is there any way to remotely access the development server?

Answer (score 1):

You could try ssh to your development server and develop from there. Remember to use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to make the your site accessible during debug.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the three specified Jackson libraries as well. That will correct the issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer to the question above?